# In Rust, what kind of syntax is ::<Template>?

Tags: rust

In the [documentation to the Amethyst game engine](https://book.amethyst.rs/book/stable/concepts/resource), I see this code snippet:

```
  // try_fetch returns a Option<Fetch<MyResource>>
  let fetched = world.try_fetch::<MyResource>();
```

How does this syntax work? What does it mean to put a template parameter right after a :: character? In the Rust book, I can only see template parameters after a function or a data declaration. What does it even mean to say try_fetch::()?

Comment: It's called [Turbofish](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/first-edition/generics.html#resolving-ambiguities).

Comment: also, read this. It may help https://techblog.tonsser.com/posts/what-is-rusts-turbofish